# Should I fill in 15-20 nail holes in my roof underlayment? If so, how?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, exterior, roofing

I goofed right off the bat when installing shingles for my garden office roof.  I forgot to trim the rake of the first shingle in the starter strip.  The net result is that it wasn't aligned properly.

(Thankfully?) I caught this pretty early and removed the improperly installed starter row.  I still have about 15-20 holes left in the underlayment (which is 30# asphalt felt).

[image]

Should I fill these in? Or just proceed with putting a new starter strip over it?

The holes are only near the edge in the starter strip. The rest of the roof is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would repair it with the same, or similar underlayment if I could. I would create small round patches, about 4 - 5  inches in diameter and then glue them down with a caulk that can stand up to those temperatures. Most roofing caulks would work well. Just be sure to make the job as smooth as possible; wipe away any excess caulk.